# How to create pandas dataframe from nested json with dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

I'm trying to create a pandas dataframe form json file. I've seen a multiple solutions to this problem which uses built in functions from_dict/json_normalize yet I'm unable to apply it to my code. Here's how my data is structured in json file:

```
     "data": [
   {
      "groups": {
         "data": [
               {
               "group": "Math",
               "year_joined": "2009"
               },
               {
               "group_name": "History",
               "year_joined": "2011"
               },
               {
               "group_name": "Biology",
               "year_joined": "2010"
               }
         ]
      },
      "id": "12512"
   },
```

When I'm trying to normalize this data with pandas function like this:

```
path = 'mypath'
f = open(path)
data = json.load(f)

test = pd.json_normalize(
            data['data'], 
            errors='ignore')
```

I just receive something like this:

```
    id      groups.data
0   12512   [{'group_name': 'Math', 'year_joined': '2009', 'gr...
1   23172   [{'group_name': 'Chemistry', 'year_joined': '2005'...
```

I want this data to look like this (solution 1):

```
    id      group     year_joined
0   12512   group1    year1
1   12512   group2    year2
2   12512   group3    year3
```

Or like this (solution 2):

```
    id      group                   year_joined
0   12512   group1,group2,group3    year1,year2,year3
1   23172   group4,group5           year4,year5
```

How can i achieve it? I tried passing 'record_path' parameter to 'json_normalize' function but it doesn't change anything. I tried to use 'DataFrame.from_dict' function to work around this but I failed. The only way I was able to get to solution 1 was to just create multiple loops that iterated through everything in json file and add it to separate list. It kinda works but takes a lot of time on bigger datasets.

How could i use built-in pandas tools to process files which are nested as dictionaries in 3rd layer of the file as presented above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect the information from the `data` dictionary

**solution 1**

```
d = {}
for group in data["data"]:
    groups = [x["group_name"] for x in group['groups']["data"]]
    d['id'] = d.get('id', []) + [group['id']] * len(groups)
    d['group'] = d.get('group', []) + groups
    d['year_joined'] = d.get('year_joined', []) + [x["year_joined"] for x in group['groups']["data"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Output

```
      id      group year_joined
0  12512       Math        2009
1  12512    History        2011
2  12512    Biology        2010
3  23172  Chemistry        2007
4  23172  Economics        2008
```

**solution 2**

```
d = {}
for group in data["data"]:
    d['id'] = d.get('id', []) + [group['id']]
    d['group'] = d.get('group', []) + [','.join(x["group_name"] for x in group['groups']["data"])]
    d['year_joined'] = d.get('year_joined', []) + [','.join(x["year_joined"] for x in group['groups']["data"])]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Output

```
      id                 group     year_joined
0  12512  Math,History,Biology  2009,2011,2010
1  23172   Chemistry,Economics       2007,2008
```

Answer (score 4):

- given you have **dict** with nested list

  1. create dataframe from overall structure
  2. `explode()` embedded list
  3. expand nested **dict** with `apply(pd.Series)`

```
d = {'groups': {'data': [{'group': 'Math', 'year_joined': '2009'},
   {'group_name': 'History', 'year_joined': '2011'},
   {'group_name': 'Biology', 'year_joined': '2010'}]},
 'id': '12512'}

pd.json_normalize(d).explode("groups.data").reset_index(drop=True).pipe(
    lambda d: d["id"].to_frame().join(d["groups.data"].apply(pd.Series))
)
```

|  | id | group | year_joined | group_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12512 | Math | 2009 | nan |
| 1 | 12512 | nan | 2011 | History |
| 2 | 12512 | nan | 2010 | Biology |

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for your example:

```py
data = [ # Original data from question
   {
      "groups": {
         "data": [
               {
               "group": "Math",
               "year_joined": "2009"
               },
               {
               "group_name": "History",
               "year_joined": "2011"
               },
               {
               "group_name": "Biology",
               "year_joined": "2010"
               }
         ]
      },
      "id": "12512"
   },
]
# Use the record_path to extract the list we are interested in, and make sure we retain ID
df = pandas.json_normalize(data, record_path=['groups','data'], meta=['id'])
# Combine the group and group_name columns into a single column as they appear mutually exclusive
df["group"] = df["group_name"].fillna(df["group"])
# Discard the now unnecessary column
df.drop(columns='group_name', inplace=True)
```

It gives:

|  | year_joined | group | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2009 | Math | 12512 |
| 1 | 2011 | History | 12512 |
| 2 | 2010 | Biology | 12512 |

To create the second dataframe:

```py
df.groupby(['id']).agg({'year_joined':list,'group':list})
```

| id | year_joined | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12512 | ['2009', '2011', '2010'] | ['Math', 'History', 'Biology'] |